# How can i show programmatically the menu that opens when long press on the home screen in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen

I want to show that menu from my application.Is it possible ?

[this menu](https://i.hizliresim.com/vyz62r.jpg)

I can just show to home screen with codes.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide an id to parent layout Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/ll_stack"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".STACK">

</LinearLayout>
```

Now set this layout as widget in acitivity by findviewbyid
check here

```
 LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.ll_stack);
    ll.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

just check this every time screen got long press it will work

Comment: I guess I couldn't ask right. I want to reach this menu in my app with intents.(The menu  opens when long press on home screen).   https://i.hizliresim.com/jAJNgL.jpg